# Making a function for a tie game in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: c++, oop, clion

I am making a tic tac toe game, and so far there is complete functionality except for a tie game instance. The program doesnt end when there isnt a winner. I am not sure how to approach this, maybe I should add to my **champion** function, or make a completely new function. Some suggestions would be great. Im a beginner so any criticism is greatly appreciated.

```cpp
    #define GRID_SIZE 3

    class TicTacToe {
    private:
    char map[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];

    public:


    void computers_turn() {
        while (true) {
            int choice = (rand() % 9) + 1;

            int row = choice / 3;
            int col = choice % 3;
            char grid_position = map[row][col];

            if (grid_position == 'X' || grid_position == 'O') {
                std::cout << "Space taken. Try again" << std::endl;
            } else {
                map[row][col] = (char) 'O';
                break;
            }

        }


    }

    // determines any winning combination, horizontal, diagonal, 
    //vertical
    void champion() {
        const char *possiblities[8]{
                "123",
                "456",
                "789",
                "147",
                "159",
                "258",
                "369",
                "753"
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

            char previous_pos = '0';
            const char *possible_moves = possiblities[i];
            bool winner = true;


            for (int index = 0; index < GRID_SIZE; index++) {
                char character = possible_moves[index];
                int entered_num = character - '0';
                int grid_space = entered_num - 1;

                int row = grid_space / GRID_SIZE;
                int col = grid_space % GRID_SIZE;

                char grid_coordinate = map[row][col];


                if (previous_pos == '0') {
                    previous_pos = grid_coordinate;
                } else if
                        (previous_pos == grid_coordinate) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    winner = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (winner) {
                puts("You win");
                exit(0);


            }

        }


    }

    // initializes game, asks user for input
    void playgame() {
        std::string input;

        while (true) {
            std::cout << "Go player one" << std::endl;
            getline(std::cin, input);
            if (input != " ") {
                char entered = input.c_str()[0];

                if (entered >= '1' && entered <= '9') {
                    int entered_num = entered - '0';
                    int index = entered_num - 1;
                    int row = index / 3;
                    int col = index % 3;
                    char grid_position = map[row][col];

                    if (grid_position == 'X' || grid_position == 'O') {
                        std::cout << "Space taken. Try again" << std::endl;
                    } else {
                        map[row][col] = (char) 'X';
                        break;
                    }

                } else {
                    std::cout << "Only numbers 1 - 9" << std::endl;
                }
            } else {
                std::cout << "Have to enter something, try again" << std::endl;
            }


        }
    }

    // generates tic tac toe grid
    void generateGrid() {
        int number = 1;

        for (int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < GRID_SIZE; y++) {
                map[x][y] = std::to_string(number).c_str()[0];
                number += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // displays updated tic tac toe grid
    void tictacToeMap() {


        std::cout << std::endl;

        for (int x = 0; x < GRID_SIZE; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < GRID_SIZE; y++) {
                std::printf(" %c ", map[x][y]);
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

    }


    TicTacToe() {
        generateGrid();
        while (true) {
            champion();
            tictacToeMap();
            playgame();
            computers_turn();


        }
    }
    };


    int main() {

    TicTacToe tic;
    tic.playgame();


    return 0;
```

Comment: "any criticism is greatly appreciated" - Here's some: `#define GRID_SIZE 3`, don't use macros for constants, this is better `constexpr int GRID_SIZE=3;`. `(rand() % 9`, `rand()` has a really low period and range. Better use what's in [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) (see also [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)). `exit(0);`, naah, you probably want to `return` from `main` instead, so destructors get a chance to run. And there's much, much more to comment on, but those are the first things I noticed.

Comment: Ohh and that `% 9` after your call to `rand()` introduces bias if the max value of `rand()` is not evenly divisible by 9. Also; where do you even seed the generator? If you insist on using `rand` there should be a call to `srand()` before first use, with a *good* seed.

Comment: Remember: The only winning move is not to play.

Comment: Suggestion: In the early phases of testing DON'T use a good seed. Always use the same seed. This makes the rand always generate the same numbers. The same numbers makes the results repeatable and much easier to test.

Comment: Welcome to SO and congrats on starting a way of programmer. I, though, recommend using a https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for getting code reviews and constructive criticism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initialize all the spaces in the grid to `''`, then after each turn you could call a function to check if the game is a tie. The function could have a for loop inside of a for loop that just checks if all the grids have a value not equal to `''`

Here is a sample function:

```cpp
bool IsGameOver(char map[][])
{
    bool answer = true;
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
       for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
       {
          char grid_pos = map[i][j];
          if (grid_pos=='')
             answer = false;
       }
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Just implement something like this

Comment: @winston mcnair was this helpful?